# Linked List Alphabetical Insertion

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to insert nodes into a linked list so the strings contained in the data of each node are sorted alphabetically. If a duplicate word is inputted, the "count" integer of a node is incremented instead. I'm given a makeLnode() function that creates a node, a isGreater() function that compares two strings, and a getLnodeValue() function that returns the string with each node.

```
lnode insertWord(char * word, lnode head) {
    /* Your code to insert a word in the linked list goes here */

    lnode temp = makeLnode(word);

    if(head == NULL) // if head is null, make head=temp
    {
            head = temp;
    }

    else if(isGreater(getLnodeValue(temp),getLnodeValue(head)) == -1) // if temp < head, place temp before head
    {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
    }

    else
    {
            lnode curr;
            for(curr = head; curr; curr = curr->next) // loop through linked list
            {

                    if(isGreater(getLnodeValue(temp),getLnodeValue(curr)) == 0) // if curr = temp, increment curr
                    {
                            curr->count++;
                            break;
                    }

                    else if(isGreater(getLnodeValue(temp),getLnodeValue(curr)) == -1) // if temp < curr, place temp before curr
                    {
                            temp->next = curr->next;
                            curr->next = temp;
                            break;
                    }

                    else if(curr->next == NULL) // if we reach the end of the list and temp > all other nodes, place temp at end of list
                    {
                            curr->next = temp;
                            break;

                    }
            }
    }


    return head;
}
```

Only some words are incremented and there are multiples of some words. My output is as follows:

```
 1. -   2 - a
 2. -   2 - is
 3. -   1 - broadcasting
 4. -   1 - emergency
 5. -   1 - be
 6. -   1 - for
 7. -   2 - this
 8. -   1 - system
 9. -   1 - system
10. -   1 - the
11. -   1 - testing
12. -   1 - seconds
13. -   1 - sixty
14. -   1 - next
15. -   1 - the
16. -   1 - test
17. -   1 - only
18. -   1 - test
19. -   1 - well
```

Comment: How about posting source for `isGreater()`?

Comment: I see that, as usual with liked-list questions, no aparrent debugging has been done.  I guess we should be grateful that there is code and output :(

Answer (score 0):

You say `// if temp < curr, place temp before curr` but actually is putting it after:

```
temp->next = curr->next;
curr->next = temp;
```

As you see your output is not ordered because of that.

There could be an issue with `isGreater` too, and there are memory leaks as well, but this should be the first thing to fix.

I don't want to refactor the entire code here since it wasn't the question, feel free to ask if there still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a node before even checking if you need to create one : in case the word is present in the list, you don't need that new node.

Then, you should browse the list until you find a greater value or you reach the end. Then you insert your node. No need to test the three cases.

For example :

```
// check for the following base cases : no node, one node, then :
lnode node = head;
while (node->next && (isGreater(word,getLnodeValue(node->next)) == 1))
{
    node = node->next;
}

// check if the next node value is the same as your word and if it is, increment its count.
if (isGreater(word,getLnodeValue(node->next)) == 0)
{
    node->next->count++;
}

// Else, create a node with the word and insert the new node after the current node :
else
{
    lnode new_node = makeLnode(word);
    new_node->next = node->next;
    node->next = new_node;
}
```

This code is not complete and is not really good but you can start with that.